# Debugging why NIC link comes up/down constantly

Tags: linux-kernel

I'm detected an issue on my Ubuntu Intel NUC where the ethernet link drops and comes up again. It's a regular pattern where the NIC goes down for 4 seconds, comes up for 12 and then goes down again for 4 seconds on a cycle.
This *may* be related to physical damage but I can't swap out the NIC as it's integrated. Obviously I'd like to confirm this before replacing any costly components.

If I remove the kernel module and re-insert it the following output appears in kern.log which is normal to me except for the last couple lines.

```
kernel: [ 1299.003606] e1000e: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Driver - 3.2.6-k
kernel: [ 1299.003608] e1000e: Copyright(c) 1999 - 2015 Intel Corporation.
kernel: [ 1299.004140] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6: Interrupt Throttling Rate (ints/sec) set to dynamic conservative mode
kernel: [ 1299.216578] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6 0000:00:1f.6 (uninitialized): registered PHC clock
kernel: [ 1299.288105] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6 eth0: (PCI Express:2.5GT/s:Width x1) 94:c6:91:a7:78:3f
kernel: [ 1299.288112] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6 eth0: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Connection
kernel: [ 1299.288256] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6 eth0: MAC: 13, PHY: 12, PBA No: FFFFFF-0FF
kernel: [ 1299.293482] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6 eno1: renamed from eth0
kernel: [ 1304.424541] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6 eno1: NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: Rx/Tx
kernel: [ 1304.424696] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eno1: link becomes ready
kernel: [ 1325.609674] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6 eno1: NIC Link is Down
kernel: [ 1330.702483] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6 eno1: NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: Rx/Tx
```

Things I've tried:

- Swapped cables
- Changed ports on the hub it's connected to (another machine on the same hub has no issues)
- Updating the BIOS
- Going back to older kernels
- Attempting to load the module with debug parameters

If I look a the module info with `$ modinfo e1000e` I can see the debug params in the output

```
parm:           debug:Debug level (0=none,...,16=all) (int)
```

but running either modprobe or insmod eg. `$ sudo modprobe e1000e debug=16` does not yield additional info in kern.log which is what I would have expected.

Unsure where to go next. If someone can tell me why I'm not getting debug info from the module that would be a great start and any additional info gratefully received.

Comment: This appears to be [bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=205047](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=205047).

Comment: Hi, we you able to find the root cause of the issue?

Comment: I upgraded the kernel version and that appears to have fixed it for a while but the issue is back sadly. I haven't managed to resolve it sadly. 
Next step is to start with older kernel version and see try and gradually roll forward until I see if it reoccurs.

Answer (score 2):

Installed a new kernel but the good news is that it seems I didn't have to. There's a bit of conflicting information on how to get debugging info but the secret was in correctly configuring dynamic debugging.

First dump every debug message for e1000e into the kernel debugFS

`echo "module e1000e +flmpt" > /sys/kernel/debug/dynamic_debug/control`

Discovered you have to do this after the module is loaded. You can cat /sys/kernel/debug/dynamic_debug/control and see how it's modified based on this command. See https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.11/admin-guide/dynamic-debug-howto.html for more information

You can also crank up the kernel logging this way as well
`echo 8 > /proc/sys/kernel/printk` but for me this didn't seem work until I'd modified the dynamic debug control settings above. I suspect this method will also provide info at module loading time but haven't taken a look.

This yielded two sets of debug information. kern.log now has plenty of debug information, plus `cat /proc/kmsg`. Both appear to show the same information.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to debug kernel code,

1. Figure out how to compile a kernel on your distro, or at least how to compile particular modules on your distro.
2. Read the source code of this module (which should also tell you how the debug feature works).
3. If necessary (you would know after doing (2)), change your kernel configuration when compiling to enable debugging.

> `$ sudo modprobe e1000e debug=16` does not yield additional info in kern.log which is what I would have expected.

Potential pitfall: You did remove the old module before trying? And it was removed, i.e. not autoloaded back?

> NIC goes down for 4 seconds, comes up for 12 and then goes down again for 4 seconds on a cycle.

Guess: The firmware (or the hardware) is buggy, and you cannot debug either of those, as the firmware is closed source, and you don't have hardware specs.

Comment: Installed a new kernel but the good news is that it seems I didn't have to. There's a bit of conflicting information on how to get debugging info but the secret was in correctly configuring dynamic debugging.

Comment: You can also answer your own question, and include the steps you did to correctly configure dynamic debugging, so the next one with the same problem knows what to do. You can accept your own answer, too.

Answer (score 0):

Two things you might want to try:

- disable pcie by adding `pcie_aspm=off` as a kernel parameter
- disabling TSO, GSO and GRO using with `ethtool -K eth0 gso off gro off tso off` (details in [this bug report](https://web.archive.org/web/20160205153351/http://ehc.ac/p/e1000/bugs/378/)).

Both come from old threads, but might still work.